# NSTextView with tokens

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

How can I add tokens, like `NSTokenField`, to a `NStextView`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a little complicated. You will need to create a custom `NSTextAttachment` for each "token" and insert it into the `NSTextStorage` for your `NSTextView`.

There is a [great post by David Sinclair at Dejal Systems](http://www.dejal.com/blog/2007/11/cocoa-custom-attachment-text-view) which explains how to do it.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know where to start looking for it. It's a great beginning.

Comment: Wow, the article was written all the way back in 2007... Does it apply to the newer iOS 7 TextKit implementation of the TextView?

Comment: The article was written for MacOS. What's the latest on iOS?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out an easy approach that uses a custom cell class for tokens:

1. Write a cell class that inherits `NSTextAttachmentCell` and reimplement
    `- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView`
    That will be the class that represents the tokens in your `NSTextView`.
2. To insert a token follow these steps:

   1. Create an instance of `NSTextAttachment`
   2. Set the cell of the attachment to an instance of your token cell class.
   3. Create an attributed string with that attachment.
   4. Insert the attributed string into the text view.

A method that inserts a token into the text view might look like this:

```objective-c
- (void)insertAttachmentCell:(NSTextAttachmentCell *)cell toTextView:(NSTextView *)textView
{
    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
    [attachment setAttachmentCell:cell];
    [textView insertText:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];
}
```

This approach is more appropriate for tokens than the one by [David Sinclair](http://www.dejal.com/blog/2007/11/cocoa-custom-attachment-text-view). There is no need to use file wrappers since we want to display dynamic contents (tokens) rather than static images.
A look at David's concepts might be useful though. He depicts a good approach to implement the drag and drop resp. copy paste functionalities.

Comment: How about on iOS, where there is no NSTextAttachmentCell class?